# OpenID Provider Down, Now What?

Tags: discussion, openid

Seems like myvidoop.com is down so now I cannot login to this site with the ID I have used for years. How can I merge my myvidoop.com OpenID accounts in StackExchange sites with my other OpenID providers such as the Google one I am using now??

Answer (score 3):

[This page](https://superuser.com/help/defunct) explains how to proceed. It's also a good idea [to have a backup](https://superuser.com/help/edit-logins).

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to log in with any other OpenID provider that you have registered the same email address with, and you will automatically be logged in to your account if you have a verified email address.